# protractor not clearing contents of input field

Tags: javascript, html, testing, protractor

when my page loads up it has a lot of fields containing information about customers (written by somebody else). in the first name field 'Jerry' appears. I want protractor to remove this and then write my name in and expect it to be there. so far i have got this:

```
var firstName = element(by.css('#cust04'));
firstName.clear();
firstName.sendKeys('John');
expect(firstName.getAttribute("value")).toEqual("Johns");
```

at the moment it says `Expected JerryJohn to equal Johns`. any idea why it wont work? p.s. i am aware it is to equal Johns not John at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

are you trying this on protractor 2.0 because I got a similar issue and the resolve for this issue was below. I do not know why it worked for me but it did.

```
var firstName = element(by.css('#cust04'));
firstName.click().clear().sendKeys('John');
expect(firstName.getAttribute("value")).toEqual("John");
```

if you have issues with the expect happening before the text gets entered then you can do this before the expect. I've only had a few instances where I've had to do the extra wait before the expect.

```
var usernameHasText = EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(firstName, 'John');
browser.wait(usernameHasText, 5000, "Failed to type in the username");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  firstName.clear().then(function(){
        var firstName = $('#cust04');
        firstName.sendKeys('John');
        expect(firstName.getAttribute("value")).toEqual("John");
    });
```

clear() - returns promise, so you need to resolve it.
And in addition you assert wrong value(for the lastName) in your code.
Also I would recommend you use:

> browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

flag, in this case you do wont need to use .then block here, because protractor in this case will wait until promise will be resolved.

Comment: try without adding browser.ignoreSynchronization = false; for now